# JPA: Can I use @Column(precision=) for string value?

Tags: jpa

I am using `@Column(precision=)` for all my string property fields until recently I found out `@Size(max=)` is a more preferable method. Is it alright if I continue to use the precision method or should I change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@Size` is an annotation from the BeanValidation API, not JPA. It can flag errors in input before the data is put in the database.

`@Column` is to define the schema for a field (column) of an entity. `precision` is clearly stated as being for numbers ([read the javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Column.html)). `length` on the other hand can define the length of the CHAR/VARCHAR in the database. So it will restrict how much information is stored in the database

Really depends what you want to use it for ...